# Python Elastic Search Boolean value

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I have documents stored in Elastic Search as

```
 {
    "has_bool_column" : false,
 }
```

Now when I am querying using python script. The result I am getting is

```
 {
    "has_bool_column" : False,
 }
```

how false (lower case) is converting to False (uppercase F)

My Python Script

```
  from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
  
  elastic_instance = Elasticsearch("http://localhost:9200/")
  res = elastic_instance.search(index="my_data")
  print(res)
```

Is Python is changing internally

Comment: `False` is a Python object. `false` is how ElasticSearch stores the "false" value. Since you're getting the result back as a Python object, it's converted to the Python object `False`.

Comment: @Maroun is there any way to prevent this ? and get the bool object in python in false also and not False

Comment: The `false` object doesn't exist in Python. You can manually convert the object to a string, and make lower-case it. I don't recommend it though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, python does it intentionally. The reason is by parsing the document, python converts (str)false to (bool)False.

Solution is to put false word in quotations. So that python knows it is a string and not to be converted to boolean.

```
 {
    "has_bool_column" : "false",
 }
```